# ASP.Net routing to use same URL for mobile pages

Tags: asp.net, mobile, url-routing

I'm building a mobile version of my website www.example.com, but rather than redirecting users to a m.example.com/ or a www.example.com/m/ I want to maintain the same URLs.

In the desktop site's Application_Start I'm already using URL routing as in the example below.

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("offers","{location}/offers","~/offers.aspx", false,
    new RouteValueDictionary {{ "location", string.Empty }}, 
    new RouteValueDictionary {{ "location", "^(city1|city2|city3){0,1}$" }});
```

so that a URL request for www.example.com/city1/offers = www.example.com/offers.aspx

Now, once I create a mobile version of offers.aspx as offers-m.aspx, I want mobile users browsing to www.example.com/city1/offers to be served www.example.com/offers-m.aspx, and the vice versa for desktop. In other words conditional routing depending on client type.

How can this be accomplished ?

Comment: Unsure why even go through the trouble - is there an issue with just making your page/s responsive (in the first place)?

Comment: just an idea, why dont you check IsMobileDevice in your offers.aspx page. if IsMobileDevice redirect it to m/{location}/offers or offers-m.aspx

Comment: I've considered responsive, adaptive and separate design options, and a separate mobile site suits the flexibility and control I need. But I don't want to show users a separate mobile url.

Comment: See this for [options/guidance for ASP.Net `WebForms`, `MVC`](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application), also from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx). Hth..